# Create folder in zip then add contents

Tags: php, zip

What am I missing? I can't seem to get the zip to actually create a folder called "plugin" and then add the contents to that folder inside the zip. This is my code. I've tried adjusting just about everything and nothing seems to create the folder first then add the contents.

```
        function zipFiles($file_names, $ftp_user, $archive_file_name, $file_path){


        $zip = new ZipArchive('plugin');
        //create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful
        if ($zip->open($file_path . '/' . $archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE){
            exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
        }

        foreach($file_names as $files){
              $zip->addFile($file_path . '/plugins/', $files);

        }


        $zip->close();


        $zip_file = 'users/' . $ftp_user . '/' . $archive_file_name;

        header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($zip_file) . "\"");
        header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
        header("Expires: 0"); 
        readfile("$zip_file");
        exit;
    }
```

If it helps - there is an actual folder called plugin that resides on the server, so if zipping that is easier, then that's OK.

Comment: What's in `$file_names`?

Comment: `readfile("$zip_file");` —— My eyes!

Comment: $file_names holds an array of names to be added to the zip, thus foreach